# Maximum sub-array sum. where is it wrong?

Tags: c++, arrays

my answer is coming 0.
what am i doing wrong in my code to find the maximum sub array sum

```
    for(k=n;k>0;k--)
    {   
        for (j=0;j<k;j++)
    {  
        sum1=0;
       for(i=j;i<k;i++)
       {
           int sum1=sum1+a[i];
       }
       ans =max(sum1,ans);
    }
    }
    cout<<ans;
```

my answer is coming 0 rather than 10 for input 1,2,3,4

Comment: The code as presented is not a [mre], but you should remove the `int` from `int sum1=sum1+a[i];`.

Comment: Will this code be submitted to an "online judge" coding site?  If so, let me warn you that implementing a triple nested loop solution is a sure sign that a "time out" error will occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probably cause (although it's hard to tell without more context) is this line right here:

```
int sum1=sum1+a[i];
```

The `int` keyword in front of `sum1` creates a new variable with the exact same name. That means it will go out of scope the minute you leave that loop. That means, the `sum1` you actually want never gets set.

Use this instead:

```
sum1=sum1+a[i];
```

and see if that solves it.

Answer (score 0):

Int sum1 = sum1+a[I];
Here sum1 is created as local variable so when you goes out of loop that variable will goes away and you get sum1 which is declare above for loop which has value 0